# Why including atomic - gives errors

Tags: c++

I'm using g++ (gcc) version 4.9.2 under ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.
I'm trying to compile the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

And get the following errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:385:56: error: ‘noexcept’ does not name a type
      memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept
                                                        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:389:53: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const noexcept
                                                     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:389:59: error: ‘noexcept’ does not name a type
       load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const noexcept
                                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:393:59: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const volatile noexcept
                                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:393:68: error: ‘noexcept’ does not name a type
       load(memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) const volatile noexcept
                                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:398:48: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
         memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept
                                                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:398:50: error: ‘noexcept’ does not name a type
         memory_order __m = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept
```

Why cant I compile this simple example ?

Comment: You should have given 1) the full compilation command and 2) its output starting from the begin (but possibly truncated).

Answer (score 9):

Look at the **first** errors, not the last ones. Later errors are usually caused by earlier ones, so looking at only the last ones is a waste of time and doesn't tell you the root cause.

The first error will be:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:38:0,
>                    from a.cc:2:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

This should be totally obvious. You didn't tell the compiler you want to use C++11.

It even tells you how to solve the problems: compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

N.B. for GCC 5 the `<atomic>` header was modified so that you *only* get that one error and not all the resulting fall-out that comes after it.